Recover User Key on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.2
I'm new to the Linux world, I'm having trouble with a Linux server Ubuntu 22.04.2. initially install the console version and then by the same means update to the Desktop version, save information and install some test software and then shut down the server, everything worked correctly, but we forgot the access credentials and now when we want to recover or change the key we cannot. I have followed procedures found in the cloud by booting in recovery mode, but pressing the shift key at the startup of the operating system does not enter recovery mode, on the contrary, it shows me a black screen with the words GRUB on the left side and to enter code, I have tried to enter the PASSWD user code,  but it does not recognize the code. I thank you in advance for your contributions to solve this problem.
Best regards.
